# php artisan migrate => Nothing to migrate.

Tags: php, linux, laravel, mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> почему не работает php artisan migrate
>   a вот когда :reset =>норм
>   но все данные удаляются в базе данных

Comment: Судя по скриншоту, всё работает. Чего вы ожидали-то?

Comment: почему данные удаляются в базе данных, или так должно быть?

Comment: При ресете-то? Конечно, так и должно быть. Вы знаете, что такое миграции?

Comment: не до конца)! я начинающий, можно ссылку на статьи и что еще касательно миграции если имеется

Comment: знаю что при ресете удаляется, а как сделать так чтоб обновили таблицу но при этом другие таблицы сохранили данные...
обычно с migrate обновляют, но у меня не получается как видно на скриншоте

Comment: Новой миграцией, очевидно. Почитайте документацию по Laravel, прежде чем продолжать.

Comment: как?опять не до конца понял ответ)

Comment: Потому что [читать ответ следует до конца](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations).

Answer (score 1):

И так, я так понимаю, проблема в понимании понятия "миграция".

Миграция в БД - это набор скриптов для БД, которые можно запустить или откатить. Поэтому есть команды в `laravel`, `php artisan migrate` и `php artisan migrate:rollback`. Если вы "накатили" (запустили) миграцию, то ее теперь можно откатить, но при повторном запуске `php artisan migrate` миграция заново не будет "накатываться", так как она уже "накачена"(установлена).

Поэтому, вы выполнили `php artisan migrate` и все ваши текущие миграции "накатились" без ошибок, повторный запуск данной команды не находит больше новых миграций и из-за этого пишет сообщение "Нет больше миграций для установки".

Если вы создадите новую миграцию, то команда `php artisan migrate` начнет установку с последней не установленной миграции, таким образом можно контролировать работу с БД и ёё структуру и в случаи ошибок быстро откатиться к предыдущей версии.

Comment: все четко! спасибо